# Performance - Functions inside functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I have some doubts regarding performance when a functional component has inner functions.

When having a functional component with an inner function, does that inner function get re-created over and over again on every render?
In that case, if I was to memoize the component with `React.memo()`, would that function be memoized as well?

Here's a dummy example of what I'm referring to:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(({genre, name}) => {
    const someFunction = genre => {
        return (genre === 'male') ? 'Mr.' : 'Ms.';
    }

    return (
        <h1>Hello {someFunction(genre)} {name}!</h1>
    );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

From the react Hooks docs :

> **Are Hooks slow because of creating functions in render?**
>
> No. In modern
> browsers, the raw performance of closures compared to classes doesn’t
> differ significantly except in extreme scenarios.
> [...]
>
> Traditionally, performance concerns around inline functions in React
> have been related to how passing new callbacks on each render breaks
> shouldComponentUpdate optimizations in child components. Hooks
> approach this problem from three sides.
>
> - The **useCallback** Hook lets you keep the same callback reference between
>   re-renders so that shouldComponentUpdate continues to work:
> - The **useMemo** Hook makes it easier to control when individual children
>   update, reducing the need for pure components.
> - Finally, the **useReducer** Hook reduces the need to pass callbacks
>   deeply, as explained below.

Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render).

Also in your example, you can put the inner function outside the function component, because it does not use anything from inside the component, like this :

```
const someFunction = genre => {
    return (genre === 'male') ? 'Mr.' : 'Ms.';
}

const MyComponent = React.memo(({genre, name}) => {
    return (
        <h1>Hello {someFunction(genre)} {name}!</h1>
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question is a bit more technical. Even tough we do can take that function out of the component, the question is if would performance be affected due to that inner function NOT being take out. In that scenario, would that function be recreated on every render (which might slow down performance a tiny bit) or would it be somewhat optimized by some React dark magic? Anyway, why are you putting hooks up on the table? There're no hooks in my example.

Comment: @zherofilia Yes, performance of different code is different. But the difference is so tiny that you won't notice (the react hooks docs emphasize that). Write clean code first.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot mate, that's what I wanted to hear (: Indeed, clean code goes first, but this was doubt that arose whilst having a debate with a folk.